# No module named 'pylbfgs'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Trying to accomplish examples from http://www.pyrunner.com/weblog/2016/05/26/compressed-sensing-python/. And everithing was OK before importing 'pylbfgs'. I'm using: 
`conda version : 4.5.12, conda-build version : 3.17.5, python version : 3.7.1.final.0`. I've made a fresh env and installed there all required modules for this task but for unknown reasons I'm stacked with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylbfgs'`. It's 4-th day that I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: did you ever fix this?